# Xcode 8: Adding UISearchBarController to UITableViewHeaderFooterView crash: nib must contain exactly one top level object

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, uisearchdisplaycontroller, uitableviewsectionheader

I am building my Section Header View in a `XIB` file:

[image]

It's a XIB file that consists of a `UISearchBarController` inside a `UIView`

I register it in `viewDidLoad` in a tableViewController:

```
tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "MessagesSH", bundle: nil), forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier: "MessagesSH")
```

I call it in the `viewForHeaderInSection:`

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

      // Below is the where the app crashes
      let headerView = tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView(withIdentifier: "MessagesSH") as? MessagesSH 

      return headerView
    }
```

When I run the app, it crashes:

`*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'invalid nib registered for identifier (MessagesSH) - nib must contain exactly one top level object which must be a UITableViewHeaderFooterView instance'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, I discovered that you cannot have any type of a controller (i.e. `UIViewController`, `UISearchBarController`, etc.) in a Xib file.  I had to use a storyboard instead of a XIB.